# JAVA Bukkit plugin connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect my MineCraft plugin to an SQL database. but I can't seem to make it... 
I am new to java programing so here goes. 
I really don't know where the error is coming from. 
My Main Java File..

```
    package com.TristanCode.MyWebVote;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import java.sql.Connection;
import code.husky.mysql.MySQL;

public class MyWebVote extends JavaPlugin implements Listener { 

    MySQL sql;
    Connection c = null;

  //On Server Start/Stop.   
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("[MyWebVote] by TristanCode has been enabled!");
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(new Main(this), this);

        //Get configuration file
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();

        //Activate SQL
        connect();
    }
    public void onDisable() {
        System.out.println("[CashCraft] by TristanCode has been disabled!");
    }

   private synchronized void connect() {
        System.out.println("Starting connection...");
        sql = new MySQL(this, getConfig().getString("database.host"), getConfig().getString("database.port"), getConfig().getString("database.dbname"), getConfig().getString("database.user"), getConfig().getString("database.pass"));

                try {
                    c = sql.openConnection();
                    c.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Tokens").execute();
                    c.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tokens (id INTEGER not null,uuid VARCHAR(70) not null,tokens FLOAT(30),PRIMARY KEY (id))").executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Connection has been established successfully! It took ms to connect.");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
}
```

And here is the main error log.

```
[14:38:48 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at code.husky.mysql.MySQL.openConnection(MySQL.java:58)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.TristanCode.MyWebVote.MyWebVote.connect(MyWebVote.java:37)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.TristanCode.MyWebVote.MyWebVote.onEnable(MyWebVote.java:26)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:341)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:313)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:721)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:543)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:621)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:607)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:371)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:336)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:632)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:540)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[14:38:48 WARN]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:254)
[14:38:48 WARN]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that way to connect to a SQL Server, assuming your code is right, check with your host to make sure the DB port is forwarded, also make sure that your ip is allowed for remote SQL. If all that is done, and good, try using this to connect.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+getConfig().getString("database.host")+"/"+getConfig().getString("database.port")+"/"+getConfig().getString("database.dbname"), getConfig().getString("database.user"), getConfig().getString("database.pass"));
```